# Webpart won't show tasks related to the list item

Tags: 2010, web-part, data-view-web-part, tasks

I have a 'Complaints' task webpart that's displayed under a (list) display form. The tasks are created by a workflow, when a complaint is created. I can get all of the tasks to appear in the webpart, but I can't filter it - I'm wanting the tasks relating to the specific complaint to appear in the webpart, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I've tried several ways:

- creating a new calculated field to extract the **ID** from the hyperlink in the 'Link' column (ID='12').  In the webpart I connected the complaint 'Id' to the new calculated field.
- Created a new calculated field to extract the **Title** from the hyperlink in the 'Link' column (ID=12, 'Complaint against B & M Builders'). In the webpart I connected the complaint 'Title' to the new calculated field.

Any ideas how I can get this webpart to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, unfortunately the Related Item field isn't connectable because it's a link.  What I always do is create a column in the Task list that the workflow uses called RelatedId, and whenever a new task is created, have the workflow populate that column with the related content's ID.  This way you can do connected web parts and filter.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on.